# Responsive wont stay inside the main div

Tags: responsive-design

How can I make the responsive carousel stay inside the div of the bit I have jssor slider in?

On my site I have jssor slider carousel inside another div but when resizing the page or testing it in a responsive tester the carousel flows over the div it is in.

AS requested the html and java is bellow

```
<article class="tz-post tz-article">
        <div class="tz-postmetadataheader">
                <h2 class="tz-postheader">Featured Auctions</h2></div>
            <div class="tz-postcontent tz-postcontent-0 clearfix">
<div class="tz-content-layout">
<div class="tz-content-layout-row">
<div class="tz-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 100%">

<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var options = {
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlaySteps: 4,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
                $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideDuration: 160,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                $SlideWidth: 175,                                   //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                //$SlideHeight: 190,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: -9,                                  //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $DisplayPieces: 4,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $ParkingPosition: 0,                              //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
                $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 4,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                    $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                    $SpacingX: 0,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 0,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 4                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                }
            };

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
 function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = $('#slider1_container').parent().width();
    if (parentWidth) {
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}

            ScaleSlider();

            if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
                $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSlider);
            }


            //if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)) {
            //    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //}
            //responsive code end
        });
</script>

<!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 5px; left: 1px; width: 660px; height: 230px; overflow: hidden;">

        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 0px; width: 660px; height: 240px; overflow: hidden;">

<!-- BEGIN featured -->
<div>
            <div class="tz-featured-wrapper">
            <div style="display:block;" align="center"><a href="{SITEURL}item.php?id={featured.ID}">{featured.TITLE}</a></div>
                <div style="display:block;" align="center"><a href="{SITEURL}item.php?id={featured.ID}"><img src="{featured.IMAGE}" style=" border: 1px solid #9ec9ec;" class="tz-rounded-top tz-rounded-bottom"></a></div>
                <div style="display:block;" align="center">{featured.BID}</div>
            </div>
</div>
<!-- END featured -->

        </div>

        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- bullet navigator container -->
        <div u="navigator" class="jssorb03" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; right: 6px;">
            <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
            <div u="prototype" style="position: absolute; width: 21px; height: 21px; text-align:center; line-height:21px; color:#000000; font-size:12px;"><NumberTemplate></NumberTemplate></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin End -->

        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora03l" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 100px; left: 8px;">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora03r" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 100px; right: 8px">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
    </div>
<!-- Jssor Slider End -->

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you scale the slider base on window width.

Let's scale the slider base on parent width then.

See

```
function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = $('#slider1_container').parent().width();
    if (parentWidth) {
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks I figured that bit out but it still doesn't work properly it still overlaps when the window is resized by dragging it and the window reaches its smallest points

Comment: What exactly does the 30 do in this bit of code window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);  it's not documented anywhere what the 30 does

Comment: setTimeout means delay call of specified code with delay in milliseconds. Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: its saying its to long to post

Comment: it doesn't can I email you the URL of the site I am working on so you can have a look? I can't post the URL in this public forum

Comment: Ok I fixed that my friend. but now I have the problem that it makes the items look fuzzy and not as bright almost like there is an overlay or something and only when changing the responsive bit to the code you gave above

Comment: If you scale the slider larger than the original size of image, it may look blurry.

Comment: Thanks but i'm not sliding an image I am sliding a combination of 4-5 intertwined <DIVs> if you look at the code you asked me to post in the first post. the code from <!-- BEGIN featured --> and
<!-- END featured --> is what is being slid